# need help on school assignment html

Tags: html

I need to recreate this: [image: I need to recreate this]

My Attempt: [image: My Attempt]

I'm trying to recreate the first picture above and the result I got was the 2nd picture I need
this is a university homework, specifically how do you add a "Use the menu to select different stylesheets" in that way below the Header, at first i tried adding another but the result is as you can see

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 200%;

}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
</body>
<h1>Welcome to my Homepage</h1>
<h2>Overview of Homepage</h2>
</html>
```

Comment: i',m just really tryna learn this part 'cause our professor didn't include in our lectures

Comment: I'm pretty sure your professor or teaching assistant would happy to answer this.

Comment: just set the `background-color` and `text-align left` for your body and add `</body>` after `h2` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .content{background-color: #2ed274; text-align: left; padding: 20px;}
        body{color: white; font-family: Arial;}
        h1 {font-size: 30px; margin-bottom: 0;}
        h2 {font-size: 15px; margin-top: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = 'content'>
        <h1>Welcome to my Homepage</h1>
        <h2>Overview of Homepage</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```